# Flutter async method slowdown app performance

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, setstate

I'm a newbie in flutter and I can't understand what I might be doing wrong. In my App there is an option for the user to change their avatar's image. He can choose an image from the gallery or take a photo. The new avatar image is saved in the **_avatarImage** field, and within the setState method the **_newImage** field is set to true, like this:

```
Future getNewAvatarImage() async {
   Image _image = .... // Take a photo or a image from Gallery
   // ...
   _avatarImage = _image;
   setState(
     () => _newImage = true;
   );
 }
```

In one part of the code I have the **compressAndUpload** method which when called compresses an image and sends it to the remote server. This method is asynchronous and is called within the **build method** whenever the **_newImage** field is true. Like this

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_newImage) {
       _newImage = false;
       compressAndUpload(_avatarImage);
    }
    return Container(
       //...
       child: _avatarImage,
       //
    );
```

The problem is that the new avatar image will take a long time to appear if the compressAndUpload method is called. If this method is commented out the new avatar image comes up quickly.

```
    if (_newImage) {
       _newImage = false;
       // New image show quickly
       // compressAndUpload(_avatarImage);
    }

    ***********

    if (_newImage) {
       _newImage = false;
       // Image takes too long to appear
       compressAndUpload(_avatarImage);
    }
```

Where is the problem? The compressAndUpload method is asynchronous and so should not cause delay for the new image to be displayed:

```
 Future<void> compressAndUpload(var image) async {
    // Compress image
    // upload image
 }
```

UPDATE:

For further clarification I show the complete code of the **compressAndUpload** method:

```
 Future<void> compressAndUpload(var image) async {

  var imageBytes = imagem.readAsBytesSync();

  saveImageToPreferences(base64String(imageBytes));

  var tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
  var path = tempDir.path;

  // Reduce size
  img.Image image = img.decodeImage(imageBytes);
  img.Image smallerImage = img.copyResize(image, width: 1000);

  File compressedFileImage =  

  File('$path\${Explika.getAluno().id}.jpg')
   ..writeAsBytesSync(img.encodeJpg(smallerImage, quality: 50));

  String _urlsegment =  Explika.producaoFlag ? 
  'https://www.remoteserver.pt' : 'http://10.0.2.2';

  var stream = http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(
               compressedFileImage.openRead()));
  var length = await compressedFileImage.length();
  var uri = Uri.parse('$_urlsegment/explika/api/upload');

  var request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);

  var multipartFile = http.MultipartFile('fotoaluno', stream, length,
      filename: '${Explika.getAluno().id}.jpg');

  request.files.add(multipartFile);

  var response;
  try {
    response = await request.send();
  } catch (e) {
    // mostrar falha de rede
    //_uploadingImagem = false;
    print(e);
    return;
  }

  //Get the response from the server
  var responseData = await response.stream.toBytes();
  var responseString = String.fromCharCodes(responseData);
  print(responseString);
```

}

Comment: You seem to be running that code in the build method of your widget, which is not the right place. Can you share where you are calling this widget and also share what your compressAndUpload method is doing?

Comment: Hello,  João. Question updated.

Comment: Just because `compressAndUpload` is `async` doesn't make it run in the background. You don't show it, but no doubt it contains compute-bound code doing the compress. You will need to look at isolates so that you can post this cpu intensive effort to another thread, and update and upload the avatar once it has been created from the image.

Comment: Also, in an async method, you should use `await readAsBytes` instead of the sync alternatives.

Comment: Running that function on the build method is part of your problem. You can't control when Flutter re renders your Widget, it can happen at any time. Having that function being called in the build method can cause all kind of issues. The decision to show the image or not should be within the Widget you are returning and not outside of it. The compressAndUpload method should be called elsewhere after you user selects the image.

Comment: I agree with @JoãoSoares. Instead of the `build` method your `compressAndUpload` should be called in `getNewAvatarImage()` method, before `setState()`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks so much for all the comments.

The problem was solved when I found that in the **pickImage method** it was possible to set the maximum width and the maximum height of the image being selected. Thus, the compression step of the selected image was not required.